# Firebase LIKE button and counter

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In a structure of Firebase like this:

```
Pictures
-pictureID
-- name
-- date

Like
-pictureID
-- userID: true
-- userID: true

likePerUser
-userID
--pictureID: true
--pictureID: true

Users
-userID
-- name
-- lastname
```

I have implemented a like system where user can likes images. (swift3)

I'm able to get the number of users that liked a specific picture by doing this:

```
ref.child("Like").child(pictureID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            print(snapshot.childrenCount)

        })
```

how can i find if a user (which i know his userID) has liked a picture (i know also it's pictureID)?

So i edit the structure and code, now i need to check if under the node likeperuser, under child currentUser is there a pictureId equal to true
but this code doesn't work...

```
ref.child("likePerUser").child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.u‌​‌​id).queryOrdered(b‌​yC‌​hild: pictureId).queryEqual(toValue: true).observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with:{(snap)in
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In NoSQL you often model your data for the use-cases that your app needs. So if your app has a use-case where you want to know what pictures the user has liked, store a list of the pictures each user has liked:

```
LikesPerUser
- userID
-- pictureID: true
-- pictureID: true
```

With this (additional) structure, looking up the likes-for-a-user is as simple as looking up the likes-for-a-picture is in your current structure.

For a good introduction to this topic, read [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watch [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).